# Jquery .trigger('click') clicks multiple times

Tags: jquery, triggers, click, keycode

I'm using this code:

```
var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
    if (keycode == '39') {
        angular.element('#nextBtn').trigger('click');
    }
});
```

But everytime I press the right-arrow key (keycode 39) it **clicks** the #nextBtn **multiple times**, is this a bug or am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: did you try to do event.preventDefault before `angular.element('#nextBtn').trigger('click');` ?

Comment: @DianaR You're a legend, great work. Thanks !

Comment: ;) will post this as an answer for future reference.

Comment: I won't, only need to wait 2 more minutes before I can accept it :)

Comment: @Goldenowner just so you know, you don't have to edit your question to include a solution or credit (in fact you really shouldn't).  Rather, the answer and the credit are given below your question in their own space.

Comment: @brandaemon Okey I changed it... I really like this site because you always get help, but people seriously cry way too fast, just saying..

Comment: @Goldenowner trust me, it's for your own good.  Oftentimes when people here see content that doesn't conform to the guidelines (which to them are obvious) they just vote down and move on.

Comment: @brandaemon I know, I wasn't talking about you. You just gave me a warning and that is very kind of you. Btw we can better delete those comments because people are gonna say that this is too chatty hahah

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do `event.preventDefault()` before `angular.element('#nextBtn').trigger('click');`